# Why is my argument when using selectionSort not working? It has issue with T, but I cant put my finger on it

Tags: java, sorting, selection-sort

Using Java, I was told to copy the selectionSort method from a text book and use it. In using it, I am having issues in the program telling me my argument selectionSort(int [], int) is incompatible, but I thought T was supposed to be many different arguments. Why is this not working? (P.S. ignore the request for user input, that is a little extra work I am adding to the assignment, if I can make the method work, I can add user input) (Double P.S, I made another method, printArray to dust off Array cobwebs but did not attach the method to the code below).

I am getting the following message from Eclipse: The method selectionSort(T[], int)
in the type Program15_4 is not
applicable for the arguments (int[],
int)

I am getting the following error message when terminating my program: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
The method selectionSort(int[], int) is undefined for the type Program15_4

```
at Program15_4.main(Program15_4.java:25)





import java.util.*;


public class Program15_4 {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] input = new int[10];
        
        
System.out.println("Please enter 10 numbers");
for (int index = 0; index < input.length; index++) {
    input[index] = in.nextInt();
}


int [] n = { 4, 8, 12, 14, 20, 24 };



System.out.println(selectionSort(n, n.length));

printArray(input);

    }


    
    

    //enter code here
    
    public static <T extends Comparable <? super T>>
    void selectionSort(T[] a, int n)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index <n -1; index++)
        {
            int indexOfNextSmallest = getIndexOfSmallest (a, index, n-1);
            swap (a, index, indexOfNextSmallest);
            
        }
    }
    private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
    int getIndexOfSmallest(T[] a, int first, int last)
    {
    T min = a[first];
    int indexOfMin = first;
    for (int index = first +1; index <= last; index++)
    {
        if (a[index].compareTo(min) < 0)
        {
            min = a[index];
            indexOfMin = index;
            
        }
    }
    
    return indexOfMin;
    
}
    private static void swap(Object [] a, int i, int j)
    {
        Object temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
    }
```

**SOLUTION: USING selectionSort() METHOD ABOVE**

```
public class Program15_4 {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {


Integer [] n = { 20, 14, 12, 24, 2, 21 };



selectionSort(n, n.length);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(n));

    }
```

Comment: What is your question? Do you get an error? If so, what is it? If not, what is the output and what do. you want it to be instead? Please [edit] your question to show more details.

Comment: Why is there an english sentence in your code? You should always comment things like this out (with //). Otherways you will almost certainly get errors.

Comment: Sorry sorry, first post on stack overflow, the "enter code here" I presume was added by stackoverflow.

Comment: I don´t know if this is also because of StackOverFlow but you miss a bracket at the end, printArray() is not a function and selectionSort() takes T[] and not int[] as it´s first argument.

Comment: Thank you for the help Lansik, and for clarification, when I attempt to change selectionSort() to take the argument int[], it makes many more issues. This is odd haha. And yes, the bracket at the end of printArray() is because my naivety of stackoverflow, my apologies.

Comment: For clarification, the bracket below printArray() is to cut the main from other methods. Can I create a method in main?

Comment: Now it makes sense. But I don´t think I can help you anymore. I didn´t take a look at these Comparables in Java or whatever they are. Sorry.

Comment: Hint: the message tells you that you try to RUN your code although it doesnt even compile. Dont do that. Dont RUN code unless everything compiles before.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments and recommendations, I just got back from a hike and will give it a shot. Thank you all, will keep you updated.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

1. Declare your array `n` to be an array of `Integer`, not `int`.  In Java, `int` is a primitive type, and can't be used for a generic type variable like `T`.  Also, don't initialize the numbers in the array in sorted order, because you want to test whether the sorting code works.  So, you could declare your array like this:

   ```
   Integer[] n = { 20, 14, 12, 24, 2, 8, 4 };
   ```
2. Your `selectionSort` function is void, meaning it doesn't return anything.  So, you can't use `System.out.println` to print its return value, because it doesn't have one.  So, just call the function:

   ```
   selectionSort(n, n.length);
   ```
3. You can print an array using the `Arrays.toString` method, like this:

   ```
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(n));
   ```

Comment: I will give it a try, thank you thank you for the suggestions!! Really helps clear much up, thank you so much.

Comment: Great!  I'm glad that worked for you.  And, welcome to Stack Overflow!  If you feel that this answer solves your problem, you can accept the answer, so that future visitors to this page will not be left thinking that the problem is still unsolved.  You can also upvote any answers to your question that you find helpful.